# Redis Sorted Set ... store data in "member"?

Tags: redis

I am learning Redis and using an existing app (e.g. converting pieces of it) for practice.

I'm really struggling to understand first *IF* and then (if applicable) *HOW* to use Redis in one particular use-case ... apologies if this is super basic, but I'm so new that I'm not even sure if I'm asking correctly :/

**Scenario:**

`Images` are received by a server and info like `time_taken` and `resolution` is saved in a database entry. Images are then associated (e.g. "belong_to") with one `Event` ... all very straight-forward for a RDBS.

I'd like to use a Redis to maintain a list of the 50 most-recently-uploaded image objects for each Event, to be delivered to the client when requested.  I'm thinking that a `Sorted Set` might be appropriate, but here are my concerns:

First, I'm not sure if a Sorted Set can/should be used in this associative manner?  Can it reference other objects in Redis?  Or is there just a better way to do this altogether?

Secondly, I need *the ability* to delete elements that are greater than X minutes old.  I know about the `EXPIRE` command for keys, but I can't use this because not all images need to expire at the same periodicity, etc.

This second part seems more like a query on a field, which makes me think that Redis cannot be used ... but then I've read that I could maybe use the Sorted Set `score` to store a timestamp and find "older than X" in that way.

Can someone provide come clarity on these two issues?  Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

Knowing that the amount of data I need to store for each image is small and will be delivered to the client's browser, can is there anything wrong with storing it in the `member` "field" of a sorted set?

- For example `Sorted Set` => `event:14:pictures <time_taken> "{id:3,url:/images/3.png,lat:22.8573}"`

This saves the data I need and creates a rapidly-updatable list of the last X pictures for a given event with the ability to, if needed, identify pictures that are greater than X minutes old ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I'm not sure if a Sorted Set can/should be used in this
>   associative manner? Can it reference other objects in Redis?

Why do you need to reference other objects? An event may have `n` image objects, each with a `time_taken` and image data; a sorted set is perfect for this. The image_id is the key, the score is time_taken, and the member is the image data as json/xml, whatever; you're good to go there.

> Secondly, I need the ability to delete elements that are greater than
>   X minutes old

If you want to delete elements greater than X minutes old, use [ZREMRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore):

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE event:14:pictures -inf (currentTime - X minutes)
```

`-inf` is just [another](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) way of saying the oldest member without knowing the oldest members time, but for the top range you need to calculate it based on current time before using this command ( the above is just an example)

Comment: Thank you -- learning curve is really high right now, so on my initial post I was still thinking relationally.  Do you happen to know the length limit for the member (json/xml data)?